# Can the conclusion of an inductive argument be that there is only one exception to the list of evidentiary claims?

Tags: logic, induction

Can this be an example of an inductive argument?

Premise 1: Country A rejected idea Z.

Premise 2: Country B rejected idea Z.

Premise 3: Country C rejected idea Z.

Premise 4: Country D rejected idea Z.

Premise 5: Country E rejected idea Z.

Premise 6: Country F rejected idea Z.

Premise 7: Country G rejected idea Z.

Premise 8: Country H rejected idea Z.

Therefore, from premises 1 – 8,

Conclusion: Country I, which is the subject of the present proceedings, is the only country to have accepted idea Z.

Comment: Country I would not have to accept or reject the idea just because the other countries rejected it. If Country I accepted the idea it would be a counter example for the claim that all countries rejected the idea. Perhaps I did not understand the question. Regardless, welcome to this SE!

Comment: Thank you! I am asking because I am trying to analyse a Court judgment. The conclusion made by the Court was that Country I is the only country to have accepted the idea, given all of the examples mentioned (i.e. rejections from Country A - H). So is the Court making an inductive argument here? Or is it an example of another type of argument?

Comment: Are Premises 1-8 the only premises? Is nothing else known about the case? (Maybe something like: some country accepted, A-H rejected, so only I accepted?) If those are really the only premises it's hard to see how the conclusion could be justified.

Comment: Courts usually say that several jurisdictions all accept a principle of law, while the results in several others are unknown. It would be unusual for a court to draw a conclusion that an idea had been rejected in the absence of a clear decision saying so.